# Use DetachedCriteria on subquery returning all fields

Tags: hibernate, jpa

i have the following query that i need to convert to Criteria

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.desc, t3.date from
(SELECT * FROM a, b, c where a.id = b.id and b.id = c.id) t1
left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
left join t3 on t1.id = t3.id
```

I read that i can use DetachedCriteria but the examples I saw so far when it only returns, say, id, for example:

```
SELECT * from t1 where t1.id in (select subquery.id from subquery);
```

Comment: Is that native SQL ?

Comment: it's originally not native sql, i am using Criteria and table a has mapping with b, c, t2, t3.  However, i encounter slowness when table a contains millions of records.  So this sql I presented is a supposed to be tuned sql.

Comment: The problem with Criteria, is that you can't do all that you can with JPQL, and it's worst with native SQL. I'll answer with an example using two column subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to write a subquery that looks like this:

```
select * from A 
where (A.col1, A.col2) in (select B.col1, B.col2 from B);
```

It is possible in criteria using [Subqueries.propertiesIn](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Subqueries.html#propertiesIn%28java.lang.String[],%20org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria%29).

```
final ProjectionList subqueryProjections = Projections.projectionList();
subqueryProjections.add(Projections.property("col1"));
subqueryProjections.add(Projections.property("col2"));

DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(B.class);
subquery.setProjection(subqueryProjections);

mainCriteria.add(Subqueries.propertiesIn(new String[] {"col1", "col2"}, subquery));
```

This will not help you for the `from a, b, c` part which is a cartesian product.

**Note:** I never used it in a plain Java environment, only with Grails with Hibernate 4.3. And it will not work with all database (H2 does not support in with multiple fields).

Comment: Informix is another environment that doesn't support multiple-field 'IN' expressions.